# XML Parser error invalid character on <b></b> tags

Tags: xml, xml-parsing, rss, cdata

I'm writing an XMLParser with NSXMLParser but i get this error: `XML Parser error invalid character (Unicode: 0xc) was found` when i try to parse a feed that contains `<b></b>` in a CDATA block.

I know it doesn't comes from my code since i get the same error with online feed validators. I also know for sure that it comes from the  tags since the error dissapears when the tags are removed.

Here is the part of the feed concerned:

```
  <item>
     <title>Title</title>
     <link>http://www.mywebsite.com/2015/07/06/article/?utm_source=rss&amp;utm_medium=rss</link>
     <comments>http://www.mywebsite.com/2015/07/06/article/#comments</comments>
     <pubDate>Mon, 06 Jul 2015 07:30:01 +0000</pubDate>
     <dc:creator><![CDATA[author]]></dc:creator>
     <guid isPermaLink="false">17898</guid>
     <description><![CDATA[description]]></description>
     <content:encoded><![CDATA[<p><b>content: </b>content.<b></b></p>]]></content:encoded>
     <slash:comments>20</slash:comments>
  </item>
```

As you can see, the  tags are at the end of the `<content>` CDATA block

Comment: The `<b>` element contains a FORM FEED (`0xC`) character. It is not allowed in XML documents; see http://www.w3.org/TR/xml/#charsets.

Comment: Ok, any idea how it could have gotten there ? The feed is generated with Wordpress

Comment: No idea. All I can say is that the parser rightly rejects the XML document. If you want to make it parseable, you must remove the offending character.